# What are the common practices and considerations for using the [[nodiscard]] attribute in C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard

`[[nodiscard]]` serves as a warning to the compiler and, subsequently, to developers, indicating that the return value of that function is important and should be used or captured.

What are the common practices and considerations (to detect possible bugs at early stage): To apply `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to any member function that returns a value (except special cases)? ...Or to apply it only to member functions that it is necessary (for example: a member function that returns a memory allocation)?

Comment: Of course `[[nodiscard]]` by default makes a better interface. The question is whether you can be bothered to type it constantly (I personally do).

Comment: I recommend using the guideline [suggested by clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize/use-nodiscard.html): add `[[nodiscard]]` on pure functions (having no side effects).

Comment: Applying the attribute to *all* functions diminishes its use, and is really too much for functions whose returned values *can* be discarded or ignored. Use it only for function where the returned value really *must* be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When to apply `[[nodiscard]]` is opinionated.

#### Minimal Approch

The most **minimal approach** is to only apply it when a function is unusable with the result discarded, and when the user is likely to misuse it without the attribute. This is what the C++ standard library does.
For example, `std::vector::empty()` is marked `[[nodiscard]]` because it could mean:

- to empty the vector
- return whether the vector is empty

To name another example, `std::launder` is marked `[[nodiscard]]` because people commonly assume that it somehow changes the pointer, and they don't need to use the result. `[[nodiscard]]` is only used in the standard to prevent such misconceptions and very likely mistakes.

#### Maximal Approach

The most **maximal approach** is to apply `[[nodiscard]]` whenever a function isn't correctly usable with the result discarded. For example, `std::max` is pointless if you discard the result, and standard library implementations are free to make it `[[nodiscard]]`. `std::vector::size()` could also be made `[[nodiscard]]` by that standard. In fact, most non-void functions could be<sup>(1)</sup>.

#### Clang-Tidy Approach

You can also stick to the clang-tidy [`modernize-use-nodiscard`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize/use-nodiscard.html) rule, which recommends `[[nodiscard]]` if all of the following conditions are met:

> - no `[[nodiscard]]`, `[[noreturn]]`, `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`, `[[clang::warn_unused_result]]` nor `[[gcc::warn_unused_result]]` attribute,
> - non-void return type,
> - non-template return types,
> - const member function,
> - non-variadic functions,
> - no non-const reference parameters,
> - no pointer parameters,
> - no template parameters,
> - no template function parameters,
> - not be a member of a class with mutable member variables,
> - no Lambdas,
> - no conversion functions.

This is obviously quite a long list and fairly pessimistic, but it's a decent starting point and can be automated.

#### Conclusion

You'll have to decide for yourself which approach to choose. There is no official guideline<sup>(2)</sup>. If you don't care about the added verbosity of `[[nodiscard]]` on a huge amount of functions, it's perfectly fine to use the maximal approach. The more `[[nodiscard]]` attributes you *correctly* use, the more bugs you are able to prevent.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Most, but not all. For example, `operator<<` overloads for stream insertion should not be `[[nodiscard]]` because discarding the resulting stream is common practice. The same applies to `operator=` overloads.</sub>

<sup>(2)</sup> <sub>[CppCoreGuidelines also hasn't decided on a recommendation](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/2109). There is consensus that there should be some guideline for `[[nodiscard]]`, but the discussion got tied up in specifics, and people lost interest in the subject.</sub>

Comment: Regarding your footnote #1: I'd say any function with no side-effect could/should be `[[nodiscard]]` in the Maximal Approach. Nice answer :)

Comment: @YSC that's a decent rule of thumb as well, but the wording for a maximal approach is really difficult to formulate. `std::max` could hypothetically have side effects if you compare types that have an `operator<` with side effects. That's also why clang-tidy doesn't add `[[nodiscard]]` to templates, I assume. Despite that, `std::max` is not intended to have a discarded result, even if there are side effects, so the "maximal approach" should apply `[[nodiscard]]` more broadly.

Comment: @JanSchultke How can the Clang Tidy Approach be automated? Unless you're referring to using a Static Analysis tool like ReSharper C++.

Comment: @JanSchultke Agreeing all the way

Comment: @Amit clang-tidy is an automatic tool. Even if you don't have an IDE with clang-tidy integration, you can use its CLI interface, and some of its rules can be applied automatically with the `-fix` option. All the `modernize-` rules offer fixes.

Comment: @JanSchultke, it makes sense to me that adhering to the Clang Tidy Approach is a prudent strategy to follow, given the considerable thought and effort put into its formulation.